# Do we need to 'Manage stock' in order to put specific products 'Out of stock'?

Tags: out-of-stock

Magento 1.9.4

We used to have Manage stock = NO in:

```
System - Configuration - Inventory.
```

We desperately need to put about 20 specific products to show as 'Out of Stock' so I changed Manage stock = YES. Now I'm just worried that the products that have Qty = 0 (we never used to specify quantity before) will not be available on the site?

Here is the big question then:

**Can you set products to status 'Out of Stock' even if 'Manage Stock' = NO?**

Answer (score 0):

The `Manage Stock` configuration has nothing to do with the stock status.

Enabling `Manage Stock` config means that you want the products qty to be decreased as customers order that product, as you could guess, setting it to disabled, means that the stock qty will remain the same as it won't be decreased when orders are performed on that product.

So, to answer your question, yes, you can have both stock status 'out of stock' and 'manage stock'=yes on the same product.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This actually caused a major issue for us as we never used to Manage stock before. The only option to get the Out of Stock option to come up IS to turn the Manage Stock to YES & since we never entered any quantity on any of our products, soon enough - they all turned to Out of Stock. So from my perspective - it's not possible to have the Global Manage Stock = yes just so that we can mass update products into Out of Stock. We ended up doing it individually = Open product-Inventory-untick Use Config Settings; YES, select Out of Stock in Stock Availability

Comment: Understood. Well, it all resumes to the business model you have. You can always turn back to database queries when you really are in a hurry to propagate a change across multiple products. However, my answer is strictly relative to the question you asked and I am saying this in order not to confuse people who read your feedback and think you can't have items out of stock when managing stock on it :) so i would ask you to please consider marking this as solution for this reason only.